# Как сделать, чтобы для IE использовался один CSS файл, а для других - другой?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Делаю так:

```
 <!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

И так:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Но выполняется и то и другое. А именно, делаю для второго:

```
 #scroll-btn {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image:url(img/logo.png);
    background-size:cover;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2rem;
    color:#FFF;
    z-index:4;
    position:absolute;
    left:45%;
    bottom:90px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:26% auto 0;
 }
```

А для первого:

```
 #scroll-btn {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image:url(img/logo.png);
    background-size:cover;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2rem;
    color:#FFF;
    z-index:4;
    position:absolute;
    left:45%;
    bottom:90px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:26% auto 0;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
 src='img/logo.png',
 sizingMethod='scale');

 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
 src='img/logo.png',
 sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Но выводится и то и другое изображение. Происходит наложение.

**Проблема в следующем**

Когда со style.css удаляю строку bg-image, то в IE отображается только одно изображение, что и нужно мне. Но когда это удаляю, то и следовательно в др браузерах не отображается. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><![endif]-->
```

для IE8 и ниже

http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii

для ie9 можно как через условные комментарии, так и через

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
    /* стили только для IE9 - IE10 */ 
}
```

так как ie10 не поддерживает условные комментарии тогда можно так

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* стили только для IE10 */  
}
```